# How do I achieve persistence even when I stop running Spring?

Tags: mysql, database, spring

I have just completed a Spring Boot tutorial of 34 videos. Im looking online and everything seems to show me how to create persistence of my data when the spring application is running. However, once I stop the program and restart it, it doesn't have the data I want saved.

So what it sounds like is I need to store this information on a database. I think I've set up a MySql server on my laptop and I have the workbench app/interface.

What might be more appropriate is connecting to an online server that I have with phpmyAdmin. In any case, how do I connect my spring application to a database instead of to a localhost:8080

Please let me know where I can look and what resources I have here as I'm kind of new to this sort of thing. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There 2 options

1. Either use persistent DB instead of in-memory storage
2. You are using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` hibernate property that will recreate db schema every time you start the application - thus its "clear" of the start. Use update or validate instead.

Comment: I have that in a .yml file. and im connecting to my spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

But how do I know that mySQL is connected to it?

Comment: *jdbc:mysql* says its mysql. App would not start if connection would fail.

Comment: my username and password fields are empty. would they be my computers name and password? I get this error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Isnt that self explainatory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set `spring.sql.init.mode=never` to not always initialize your database using scripts.
This way you'll find all data you saved even when re-run the app.